# Generic tree implementation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, tree

Is anyone aware of a generic tree (nodes may have multiple children) implementation for JavaScript?

It should be able to do atleast these things,

1. get parent node.
2. get children nodes.
3. get all the descendants.
4. remove all the descendants.
5. remove children nodes.

Some implementation similar to Adjacency List Model.

**Background:** I needed JavaScript based hierarchical data storing for my webpage i could not find a good JavaScript implementation of generic trees so what i did is i used ajax to store hierarchical data into database using Adjacency List Model and php. The problem comes when the user is opening the same page in two tabs of same browser or opened the page in two different browsers because both the instances are writing to same table reading from same table which is causing me problems any possible work around for this also answers my question.

**Edit:** *Performance* is really not my constraint at any point of time i will not have more than 50 entries.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this.. http://www.jstree.com/

Comment: @RJ45 it is not related to look and feel it is related to hierarchical data storing.

Comment: Sounds really like a simple XML structure......Have you considered `window.DOMParser()` [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_parser.asp)?

Comment: @Passerby thanks for the suggestion which i never knew before. i was going through those pages that isn't much,few minutes of googling also dint give me much..... can u plz direct me to some page which actually shows how to add delete entries into the XML string.

Comment: Please don't suggest DOM. From an API perspective the DOM is quite ugly for accessing a normal tree.

Comment: @JoachimSauer please can u elaborate ur comment. i'm fairly new to XML i feel doing it ugly is better than not doing it can u guide me to some pages which can actually tell how to do it. Few minutes of googling also dint get me much.

Comment: @wh0: I'm not arguing the usefulness of the DOM API as an API to access XML/HTML content. I'm saying that the API is clumsy and convoluted *if you try to use it as a generic tree API*.

Comment: @JoachimSauer i'm saying generic tree anyway i dint get any proper implementation of it. So instead reinventing the wheel writing library for generic tree implementation with very less javascript experience that i have. I could  do it the clumpsy way which is possible please guide me to any pages which implements this way.

Answer (score 9):

You can try this: https://github.com/afiore/arboreal

Or this: https://github.com/mauriciosantos/buckets/ (only Binary Searched Trees, but olso other data structures)

If you need anything more sophisticated, you will need to write your own library (or at least one object with all methods you desribed).

EDIT:

This is my simple code to achieve tree functionality. Remove all descendants and remove all children is in fact the same... so:

```
function Node(value) {

    this.value = value;
    this.children = [];
    this.parent = null;

    this.setParentNode = function(node) {
        this.parent = node;
    }

    this.getParentNode = function() {
        return this.parent;
    }

    this.addChild = function(node) {
        node.setParentNode(this);
        this.children[this.children.length] = node;
    }

    this.getChildren = function() {
        return this.children;
    }

    this.removeChildren = function() {
        this.children = [];
    }
}

var root = new Node('root');
root.addChild(new Node('child 0'));
root.addChild(new Node('child 1'));
var children = root.getChildren();
for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        children[i].addChild(new Node('second level child ' + j));
    }
}
console.log(root);
children[0].removeChildren();
console.log(root);
console.log(root.getParentNode());
console.log(children[1].getParentNode());
```

Run it in Chrome (or other browser which supports console).

Comment: I dont want to reinvent the wheel and binary tree dont work for me and also i'm having little experience in JavaScript which i dont think really enough to write the new library. how about using using XML structure as told by @Passerby in the above comments  which i feel little better than writing a new library does anyone written any stuff like that ? please respond

Comment: as @Joachim Sauer wrote, this is not a good idea to use DOM, and I will never suggest to use it to accomplish this task.

Comment: Your edited question doesn't suit question title. Check my edited answer. I provided example JS code.

Comment: this answer was very useful for me at least, thanks for taking your time

Comment: Nice work. A quick little change to make it easy to add sub-child nodes in the above example is to add return in the addChild() method. return this.children[this.children.length -1];

Comment: What purpose does the getChildren function serve, if you can just reference the children variable directly? It's not a private variable like in Java.

Answer (score 3):

Although you did say "generic tree", what your *specific requirement* sounds simple enough for an already built-in `DOMParser`.

I respect other programmers' opinions, but still I think you can give `DOM` a try and see if it fits you.

Here's an simple illustration on how it works:

```
var tXML="<root><fruit><name>apple</name><color>red</color></fruit><fruit><name>pear</name><color>yellow</color></fruit></root>";
var tree=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(tXML,"text/xml");
//get descendants
var childs=tree.documentElement.childNodes;
for(var i=0;i<childs.length;i++)
{
 if(childs[i].nodeName=="fruit")
 {
  document.write(childs[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].textContent);
  document.write(": ");
  document.write(childs[i].getElementsByTagName("color")[0].textContent);
  document.write("<br />");
 }
}
//get child node
var appl=tree.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("fruit")[0];
document.write(appl.getElementsByTagName("name")[0].textContent+"<br />");
//get parent node
document.write(appl.parentNode.nodeName);
document.write("<br />");
//remove child node
if(tree.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("color").length>1)
{
 var clr=tree.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("color")[1];
 clr.parentNode.removeChild(clr);
}
document.write("<textarea>"+(new XMLSerializer).serializeToString(tree)+"</textarea><br />");
//remove descendants
while(tree.documentElement.childNodes.length>0)
{
 tree.documentElement.removeChild(tree.documentElement.childNodes[0]);
}
document.write("<textarea>"+(new XMLSerializer).serializeToString(tree)+"</textarea>");
```

I didn't "simplified" those long function names, so you may get a better idea.